# how to set micronaut to generate docker images

Tags: docker, kotlin, gradle, micronaut

I'm new to gradle kotlin and micronaut. by following the official guide [create your first micronaut app gradle kotlin](https://guides.micronaut.io/latest/creating-your-first-micronaut-app-gradle-kotlin.html) I made it run OK on my mac M1, but the task to generate the docker image fails:

```
Could not build image: no matching manifest for linux/arm64/v8 in the manifest list entries
```

this is expected I guess: by looking at the generated Dockerfile this is what I get:

```
FROM openjdk:17-alpine
WORKDIR /home/app
COPY layers/libs /home/app/libs
COPY layers/classes /home/app/classes
COPY layers/resources /home/app/resources
COPY layers/application.jar /home/app/application.jar
EXPOSE 8080
ENTRYPOINT ["java", "-jar", "/home/app/application.jar"]
```

so an explicit platform should be specified along with the `FROM`.
If I got it right, micronaut's plugin uses [Gradle Docker Plugin](https://bmuschko.github.io/gradle-docker-plugin), but I'm not finding the right piece of instruction to override the original from assertion that it generates.

Comment: Please share the build.gradle file with us

Answer (score 3):

The problem with the default settings of the Micronaut Gradle plugin is, that it uses `openjdk:17-alpine` as a base image. This image is only available for `amd64` architectures. Your M1 Mac would like `aarch64`.

Here is how I solved the problem with my projects.

```
tasks.named("dockerfile") {
    baseImage = "eclipse-temurin:17.0.5_8-jre-jammy"
}
```

This will work on `aarch64` (aka `arm64`) and `amd64`.

Answer (score 2):

Following the [documentation](https://micronaut-projects.github.io/micronaut-gradle-plugin/latest/#_building_docker_images):

> The default uses an openjdk:17-alpine base image, however you can easily switch the base image to use by using the baseImage property of the dockerfile task:
>
> ```
> tasks.named("dockerfile") {
>  baseImage = "oracle/graalvm-ce:22.2.0-java11"
> }
> ```

Comment: ```> Could not create task ':dockerfile'.
   > Could not set unknown property 'baseImage' for task ':dockerfile' of type com.bmuschko.gradle.docker.tasks.image.Dockerfile.
```

Comment: Can you please edit your question and show the whole build.gradle?

Comment: absolutely correct. one thing tough, since your are referring to a GraalVM image but the `dockerfile` task is supposed to build an Docker image with a fat jar, not the native image.

Comment: I just quoted the docs. I think it is up to @Bertuz to select the correct base image. The OpenJDK image is available for `arm64`, you just need to specify the correct tag.